# Copy But Unable to Paste within a Excel Worksheet

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, copy-paste, power-query

I have two worksheets in an excel file in which I can't paste copied data within the worksheet. I click on the next cell after copy and the rotating dashes disappear or when I right-click the paste function is grayed out and nothing happens. Each of the two worksheets have data from loaded tables refreshed by power queries. I added a searchable list to each of these tables to create named range drop down list on each worksheet.  Could this be the issue?

I have have narrowed down the specific issue today.  The issue is when I created the searchable list for multiple cells I need to go into VBA for the worksheet and put in the following:

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.Calculate
End Sub

This will auto calculate the worksheet each time a cell is selected within the worksheet and refresh the search list (as if you manually clicked "Calculate Now" on the Formulas bar) so that it is not stuck on the last search from another cell in the workbook. I am not certain but believe what is needed is to modify the VBA code to auto calculate for the specific cells or range that are specifically using the searchable drop down list.  However, I do not know the code to make this happen.  Any suggestions? I hope this is clear.

Comment: Excel 2007 and Power Query??  Can you be a bit more specific about the searchable list? It is totally not clear what you have on your spreadsheets. Edit your question to provide more detail, then post a comment. Again, edit your question. Do not put the details into comments.

Comment: Can you take a simple example of the problem (e.g., copying *one* cell) and give us an exact description of what you do (e.g., click in cell ```A1```, type Ctrl+C, click in cell ```B1```, …, and then what?)?  If possible, post images (screenshots or photographs) *in addition* to a verbal description.  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Are the worksheets or the workbook protected?

Comment: No the worksheets and workbook are not protected.